# How to send binary data from an Google Chrome Extension to a native application

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am sending data from a Google Chrome Extension to a native application developed in C#, however, this works only when I send short text messages but this does not when data is binary (JSON encoded).

For example, to send a command, I am calling, from the extension:

```
port.postMessage({ command: 'Rates', info: request.setRates });
```

where `port` is the native messaging application connection and `request.setRates` is `{setRates: "framesPerSecond=15&audioBitrate=22050"}`

That is received perfectly through STDIN in the C# application.

However, if I call this instruction:

```
port.postMessage(request.binaryStream);
```

Where `request.binaryStream` is `{"data":[26,69,223,163,163,66,134,129,1,66,247,129…122,235,208,2,56,64,163],"contentType":"x-media"}`.

That is badly received in the native application. Data length is about 77 KB and in that case, I received things like: `0,215,214,171,175,125,107,235,95,94,250,215,215,190,181,........`, and of course it is an invalid JSON string. It seems that some kind of buffer overrun is being produced.

How can this be done?

EDIT:

Last attempt at the moment is to base64 encode the array:

```
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
    e.data.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(appId, { binaryStream: Uint8ToBase64(new Uint8Array(buffer)) }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
        stopStream();
    });
```

With that, this is sent to the native application (one immediately after the other):

```
{command: "Binary", data: "GkXfo6NChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKIbWF0cm9za2FCh4EEQo…ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeow=="}
{command: "Binary", data: "QgaBAACA+4O2l3/8ZtVmH2JXfcZSfs+ulepr+aF2U5d+kW0SDu…fgBgDv16uSH4AY6Q9YA4dcvrl9cvrl9cvrl9coHrr0AI4QA=="}
```

And this is received in the native application:

```
^  {"command":"Binary","data":"QgaBAACA+4O2l3/8ZtVmH2JXfcZSfs+ulepr+aF2U5d+kW0SDuRqP9n9baILWx2vK/6vraUaEqNo9Tf7htznm8o72wjRTzgjZFyfSf+k4BZDp9luH6Un1JWAhbNem.........ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddeow=="}
```

Notice that the received data is the second sent data, but the end of that received data is the end of the first sent data. So, the buffer overrun maybe is correct. Any solution to this? I had this same program using TCP Sockets and it works, but now, I need to use Native Messaging. Is the STDIN buffer very small?

Jaime

Comment: The nativeMessaging API uses JSON serialization which doesn't work with typed arrays, array buffers, and other advanced types. You'll need to convert it manually to a standard array or into a string.

Comment: @wOxxOm please see the edited question. I am sending a base64 string now, not a binary array.

Comment: To send multiple messages switch to using port-based chrome.runtime.connectNative

Comment: Am I not using port-based connectNative already?

Comment: You didn't show that code so I assumed you're not.

Comment: I thought it could be clear when using `port.postMessage(request.binaryStream);`, since `port` is only gotten by using `port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.xxxx.yyyy');`. Or is there another way to get a `port`?.

Comment: Sure, postMessage may be used with BroadcastChannel or MessageChannel or it could be some custom thing.

Comment: Old question but in such cases one can use base-64 encoding to send the binary data